# how to update array in crate

Tags: php, crate

I would like to know how I can update a value stored in an array, in crate.io

- I have a blog table - `blog_tbl`
- A  column, with data type array - `tags`
- A `id` column
- Inside the tags column I have - `["tag1","tag2","tag3"]`

I would to know how I would go about changing `'tag1'` to `'tag99'`

I tried

```
update blog_tbl set tags['tag1'] = 'tag99' where id = '1';
```

Also how would I add one the the end? so making it -

```
["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"]
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible currently. Array elements can only be selected using the subscript notation (e.g. `select tags[1] from blog_tbl;`) but not updated. Maybe add a GH issue requesting that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern found here: https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/occ.html#optimistic-update

However, that requires you to perform the modification on client side. Pseudo code:

```
updated = False
while not updated:
    cursor.execute('SELECT array_field, "_version" FROM table WHERE id=1')
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    current_array_field = row[array_field]
    current_array_field.append('newtag')
    cursor.execute('UPDATE array_field = current_array_field WHERE id=1 AND "_version" = row[version]')
    if cursor.rowcount > 0:
        updated = True
```

This will make your update semi safe for concurrent updates of the same field.